# advices on backing up storage drive

Tags: hard-drive, backup

I have a storage drive that needs to be backed up in case the drive fails... my OS is not on this drive... I was thinking RAID 1 might be what I needed, but everywhere I read, everyone says NO to RAID 1 backup...

So what I'm asking is if there is a good way to backup this storage drive that's 3TB? I'm also constantly removing and adding things to this drive so this backup needs to be something automatically done and easily recoverable.

Some things that doesn't matter for this backup:
If I accidentally delete a file, thats fine since its just my fault
if it gets destroyed by natural cause/theft... I have other things to worry about
if a power surge kills 2 drives at the same time, can't that be protected by UPS or surge protectors

Thanks in advance

TL:DR
I need a Windows7 software that automatically syncs my 3 TB storage drive and a 3 TB backup drive.

changes to the storage drive = changes to the backup drive

if storage drive dies, I can rename my backup to storage and continue to use my data

Comment: RAID is not for backup, it's for redundancy.  Get a 3TB storage device (DAS or NAS), and backup to it using one of a plethora of backup software packages that support incremental or differential backups.  What's your actual question?

Comment: I need some kind to automatic backup for my 3TB storage drive to another 3TB backup drive. "a plethora of backup software packages" seems like something that needs to be manually done

Comment: Software requests amount to shopping questions and are considered off-topic here at SU.  There are MANY backup software packages out there that will do what you want (most).  Please go try some and come back with specific problems/questions. :)

Comment: As techie said, there are virtually countless backup tools that also do automatic or scheduled backups. Your situation is pretty common, so this is basic functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are misinterpreting, a RAID 1 volume is not a backup on it's own.

You need to put the backup on a separate volume than where your original data resides. You can use RAID 1 if it's a different storage volume than where your original data resides.

What you can do in your case is just add another drive in your machine or on a separate machine in the network and use Rsync (linux) or Robocopy (windows) to keep your drive in sync.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear, I don't mean to use the same drive to backup. Robocopy seems to be a command line thing? I need something that automatically copies the storage drive to the backup drive

Comment: Just schedule it then, windows has a nice scheduler.